# Local Storage Jquery

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I'm working on local storage using jQuery. I've got an input field in which you can type some text, press enter, refresh and the text is still there. So that's working fine.

But I want to combine it with a different function I wrote. In this function a user can click on a grey button which will then "activate" it so it turns red, and it will add a 1 to the container. It's a "like button".

So how can I save the click counter information (button turning red, and value updated) using local storage?

I made this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yazuri/7ZxMK/

```
jQuery(function ($) {

  if (typeof (window.localStorage) != "undefined") {


      $("input[type=text]").val(function () {
          return localStorage.getItem(this.id);
      });

      $("input[type=text]").on("change", function () {
          localStorage.setItem(this.id, $(this).val());
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/7ZxMK/1/)**

```
 $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
     $(this).val(localStorage.getItem(this.id));
 });


 $("input[type=text]").on("change", function () {

     localStorage.setItem(this.id, $(this).val());
 });
```

---

You cannot write it in this way `$("input[type=text]").val(function () {})`. There is not event on *val*.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the counts from the "hearts"

Updated your Fiddle

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZxMK/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.clickheart').click(function () {
        $(this).find(".output").html(function (i, val) {
            if (val < 1) {

                $(this).addClass('heartrood');
                localStorage.setItem("hearts",  val * 1 + 1);
                return val * 1 + 1;

            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('heartrood');
                localStorage.setItem("hearts",  val * 1 - 1);
                return val * 1 - 1;
            }
        });
    });


});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but the code isn't working for me. I've updated my fiddle with your code. Could you take a look? Maybe I'm using it wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/Yazuri/7ZxMK/7/

Comment: Thanks for the help again but its still not working. the output/heart is still not getting saved at the local storage.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZxMK/9/)***</kbd>

1. Retrieve and save the total number of clicks
   `var result = $(".output").text();
   localStorage.setItem('click', result);`
2. If the local storage exists with key *click* show it in the div
   `if (localStorage.getItem('click') != null) {
       $('.output').text(localStorage.getItem('click'));
   }`

Hope it helps...!!